# RDP kill a program specifically

Tags: windows, batch-file, rdp

I know that you can use tskill to kill processes in a batch file, among other things, but...I have users that remote desktop into a Windows Server 2003 box to run a Microsoft Access program. Occasionally, if someone RDPs in the Access Program will already be open (meaning they have entered someone else's session). This means they are using someone else's Access log on and I have certain forms that record that info and use it to autoemail people reminders. Since everyone uses the same program only on the server, I have all rdp login as the same user. When I tried to do a tskill batch program for msaccess.exe, it killed the Access of everyone logged in--doh! I can't see making everyone log in when they rdp in, so I am hoping the answer isn't make a log in for everyone in the enterprise and then get to their computers to change their save rdp log on information. Is there a way to run something like tskill for ONLY the current session? The batch command I was using is taskkill /f /im msaccess.exe . Thank you in advance for your time and your replies.

Comment: Hi, you might find it better to ask this on superuser or serverfault sites - its not really programming.

Comment: take a look into the task manager or process explorer on that server and report back if there are multiple msaccess.exe instances, one for each user.  If so maybe we can kick-off a specific user via WMIC + $PID without affecting the other sessions.  or does the box have powershell making all this easier.

Comment: No. If only one access is running then you'll kill it. Maybe this c:\Windows\System32>tsdiscon /?
Disconnects a terminal session.

TSDISCON [sessionid | sessionname] [/SERVER:servername] [/V]

  sessionid           The ID of the session.
  sessionname         The name of the session.
  /SERVER:servername  Specifies the Terminal server (default is current).
  /V                  Displays information about the actions performed.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this script will do the trick.

```
:: Find the current session.
FOR /F "tokens=3 delims= " %%F IN ('query session %USERNAME%') DO SET SESSIONID=%%F
:: Kill all msaccess processes *in this specific session*.
taskkill /FI "SESSION eq %SESSIONID%" /IM msaccess.exe /F
```